# Facebook custom photo and video sharing action in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have video and photo sharing working fine in an iOS app using UIActivityViewController.

Now I want to upgrade it so that the app posts a custom OpenGraph story to the timeline. Something like "User posted Video from MySuperApp".

I've got the all the iOS side written, and I've got a Facebook app created and configured in the project, login, etc.

I'm a bit frustrated by the rest of the documentation, though:

- The submission guidelines speak about a "user generated photos" permission that doesn't seem to be available anywhere in the app settings, or anywhere else in the documentation. Is that still required? Is there a similar permission for videos?
- It says "Photos must be original and can only be those taken with a camera by the person who is publishing them". The app allows adding annotations/drawings on top of a photo. Does that still count as "original"? And I guess the normal image controls allow selecting images from an album, so I have no way to enforce this, do I? (Other than writing a completely custom camera control, I guess...)
- The API allows to "stage" a photo for a story. Is it possible to stage a video, or do I need to upload it externally? Can I refer to a video in a user's album in a story?
- Is it possible to use FBDialogs to post a story about a video, or do I need to write my own?

**Update**:
Current status: I wrote my own UIActivity to share on Facebook and my own activity view controller.

Making a custom story about a photo is straightforward, and covered by documentation and examples, but to summarize:

- stage photo, returns url
- create object, returns id
- create action (returns id)

Make sure you set "explicitly_shared" to true, so the action appears in the timeline. It is a good idea to follow their recommendations for error handling as well, otherwise it is a pain to debug.

I am not further with videos, though. Uploading a video is easy ([FBRequest requestForUploadVideo]), but that returns an id. So far I have not been able to use this id in either an object or an action. Querying the graph API for that id doesn't return any information. The video appears on the timeline by itself as well.

I'm tempted to just ditch the custom story about the video.

**Update**:
Okay, based on the feedback here and on the Facebook group I have to assume that it is not possible to upload and share a video as part of a story. I'm going to strip the feature down to just upload the video to the album.